# Can't define class in python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

CODE::

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


class Library:

    def __init_(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title(" Library Management System ")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")

        MTy = StringVar()
        Ref = StringVar()
        Title = StringVar()
        fna = StringVar()
        sna = StringVar()
        Adr1 = StringVar()
        Adr2 = StringVar()
        pcd = StringVar()
        MNo = StringVar()
        BkID = StringVar()
        Bkt = StringVar()
        BkT = StringVar()
        Atr = StringVar()
        DBo = StringVar()
        Ddu = StringVar()
        sPr = StringVar()
        Lrf = StringVar()
        Dod = StringVar()
        DonL = StringVar()

        #============================================FRAMES=================================================#

        MainFrame = Frame(self.root)
        MainFrame.grid()

        Title_Frame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, padx=40, pady=8, bg='cadet blue', relief=RIDGE)
        Title_Frame.grid(side=TOP)

        self.lblTitle = Label(Title_Frame, font=('arial', 46, 'bold'), text=" Library Management System ")
        self.lblTitle.grid(sticky=W)

        ButtonFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, width=1350, height=100, padx=20, pady=20, bg='Cadet Blue', relief=RIDGE)
        ButtonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        FrameDetail = Frame(MainFrame, bd=0, width=1350, height=50, padx=20, relief=RIDGE)
        FrameDetail.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        DataFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=1, width=1300, height=400, padx=20, pady=20, relief=RIDGE)
        DataFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        DataFrameLEFT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=800, height=300, padx=20, relief=RIDGE,
                                   font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), text=' Library Member Info ', bg='Cadet Blue')
        DataFrameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT)

        DataFrameRIGHT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=300, padx=20, pady=3, relief=RIDGE,
                                    font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), text=' Book Details ', bg='Cadet Blue')
        DataFrameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        application = Library(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Error::

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Jedi/PycharmProjects/LMS/main.py", line 5, in 
> class Library:   File "C:/Users/Jedi/PycharmProjects/LMS/main.py", line 62, in Library
> application = Library(root) NameError: name 'Library' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: That is not the error. That is just saying where the error is. Post the rest of the traceback.

Comment: If you want an empty class, use `class Library: pass`

Comment: Post the full error code please

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jedi/PycharmProjects/LMS/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Library:
  File "C:/Users/Jedi/PycharmProjects/LMS/main.py", line 62, in Library
    application = Library(root)
NameError: name 'Library' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So the error came from a line of code that you have not included in your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        application = Library(root)
        root.mainloop()

Comment: I don't understand how the two snippets are connected. A class body can't be null - that's a syntax error. On the other hand, the erroring line is supposedly inside the class, but `if __name__ == '__main__':` by convention is at the top level. Again, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: It looks like your `if __name__ == '__main__'` is indented. That is an error. It should not be indented.

Comment: No problem is not there in indentation

Comment: You're trying to call Library from inside the definition of Library. Not from inside a Library method. Not from outer scope. Either your indentation is wrong or your logic is.

Comment: After indentation, the error has changed to::

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jedi/PycharmProjects/LMS/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    application = LMS(root)
TypeError: LMS() takes no arguments

Comment: You sure your placing the `if` in the same indentation level as `class` ?

Comment: Yes, I have if in the same indentation level as class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your indentation is wrong, you have to place the `if` on the same indentation level as `class`, like:

```
class Library:
   .....

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ....
```

Secondly, but most importantly, your `def __init_()` has a typo, it should be `__init__()` with two underscore trailing and leading init, but you gave just one(trailing).

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
.....
```

But even after doing all this, you will get another error at `Title_Frame.grid(side=TOP)`, because `grid()` has not option `side`, it is the option of `pack()`, so change that to:

```
Title_Frame.pack(side=TOP)
```